# Log Messages Not Showing Up Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I debug my application on LG G3 everyday and today magically Android Studio started not showing `Log.d()` messages which was working fine yesterday.. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set this configuration in logcat.

[image]

Comment: ahhh No Filters.. I wouldn't think that it changed one day after another by its own. Thank you.